# Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, LoggerMessageAttribute, and Message Templates structure capturing operator

Tags: c#, .net, logging

Message Templates has a `@` structure capturing operator used to provide a hint the argument structure should be preserved.

> Prefixing a property name with the @ structure capturing operator is a hint that the the structure of the corresponding argument should be preserved, for example, by serialization.

[Message Templates](https://messagetemplates.org/#implementations) claims Microsoft.Extensions.Logging has support for message templates.

Why do I get a compiler error when trying to use the structure capturing operator with `LoggerMessageAttribute`?

```cs
public static partial class Log
{
    LoggerMessage(
        EventId = 9001,
        Level = LogLevel.Error,
        Message = "Something happened at {@point}")]
    public static partial void SomethingHappenedAt(ILogger logger, System.Drawing.Point point);
}
```

```cs
Log.SomethingHappenedAt(_logger, new System.Drawing.Point(1, 2));
```

Produces the following compiler errors:

> SYSLIB1014 Template '@point' is not provided as argument to the logging method

> CS0103 The name 'point' does not exist in the current context

Removing the structure capturing operator removes the compiler error but I do not see the `Point` object being output to the `JsonConsole`. It looks like `ToString()` is being used instead.

```json
{
  "Timestamp": "15:26:47 ",
  "EventId": 9001,
  "LogLevel": "Error",
  "Category": "Blah.Blah.Blah",
  "Message": "Something happened at {X=1,Y=2}",
  "State": {
    "Message": "Something happened at {X=1,Y=2}",
    "point": "{X=1,Y=2}",
    "{OriginalFormat}": "Something happened at {point}"
  },
  "Scopes": []
}
```

How can I keep the structure of `point` in the JSON and avoid using `ToString()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in [.NET 8](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/78013).

Comment: This is now confirmed as fixed in dotnet 8.

Answer (score 1):

This was [fixed](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/60968) in .NET 7.  I was also included in a [.NET 6 servicing release](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/64779).

Comment: That is a different issue to allow using reserved keywords as a variable name.

Comment: You're correct — my mistake.